# I can't animate a surface with Mayavi

Tags: python, animation, surface, mayavi

I'm trying to do a simple animation of a surface with Mayavi, but due to the lack of online examples (the few are extremely unclear or not useful) and official documentation, I'm struggling a lot. I wrote a very simple code to show where I've gone so far

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
import time

#Meshgrid + u + Surface

x = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
y = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
u = np.ones((10,10))
surf = mlab.mesh(X,Y,u)

#Surface animation

@mlab.animate(delay=1000)
def anim():
    for n in range(1,10):
        global u
        print(n)

        u = u+1
        surf.mlab_source.scalars = u
        yield
anim()
mlab.show()
```

So very simple, every iteration I pass from a 10x10 matrix of ones to a 10x10 matrix of twos and so on.

The problems I've encountered are 3

- I really can't understand what `mlab_source.scalars` does: fundamentally I don't know how to tell it that the z axis is changing and in doing so it follows the variation of `u`
- Mayavi opens up, but the grid is all plane and black, like there is some issues with `u`
- I don't understand what `yield` does: in the actual code I'm writing it stops the computation in a lot of advance (like in 300 steps it stops it at the step 29), but I can't remove it

I really can't get my head around, it's weeks I'm trying, hope somebody helps. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I tried to extend @E.Klahn code in a case resembling more mine

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

s = 0.01
x = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
y = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.ones((10,10))

m = mlab.mesh(X, Y, Z)

@mlab.animate(delay=20)
def anim():
     for i in range(1,100):
         m.mlab_source.z = np.ones((10,10))*s*i
         yield

 anim()
 mlab.show()
```

But I obtain only a flat surface going up, not a tridimensional object evolving, such as in his code.

Edit2:

Here the working code just copying the example of @E.Klahn, which I thank very very much

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

x = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
y = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
X,Y=X.T,Y.T            #seems an important command
u = np.ones((10,10))
surf = mlab.surf(X,Y,u)

@mlab.animate(delay=500)
def anim():
    for n in range(1,10):
        print(n)

        surf.mlab_source.scalars = 1+np.sin(X)*np.sin(Y)*np.sin(n)
        yield
anim()
mlab.show()
```

I just print it to give continuity to code above and to spot the differences.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to animate a flat surface that moves "up" along the z-axis, is that correct? In that case, I have two comments, that don't solve your problems alltogether, but it is something to start playing with. The first is that the documentation for `mlab.mesh` states that if you use `np.meshgrid` then you need to transpose the resulting `X` and `Y` (see `help(mlab.mesh)` in a Python-terminal). The second is that when the surface moves, the camera does not move, so you will run into the problem that a surface is in fact animated, it just moves out of view. See `mlab.move`.

Comment: @E.Klahn I actually wanted a box, not a flat surface. This box has a surface that is given by the X,Y meshgrid, and an height given by u, that in this case should be increase at every step. Is the simplest example of evolving surface (in 3d space) I can imagine

Comment: This is one of the problems then. I think that a mesh like this will not give you a box, since you are inputting all values of U to be the same. Consider that a box has surfaces both at Z=0 and at Z=1. Did you see that this actually gave a box before you tried animating the box?

Comment: @E.Klahn that's in fact the second point: I don't have any third dimension! Just a flat surface

Comment: So we are talking about the same thing then, right? Try figuring out how to plot a non-moving box first. I suggest using `triangular_mesh` to try and do that. Then when that works, see if you can animate it.

Comment: @E.Klahn I have no problem in plotting a surface, in fact I even managed to do some kind of animation (even if didn't seem to move) in my extended code, but I'm having two issues: the kind-of-"animation" stopped abruptly at a certain iteration due to the `yield` command, I don't know why. And I don't understand what the mayavi commands do, in fact in this simpler code the animation doesn't work at all, and doesn't even plot a surface.

Comment: The reason that you are not getting a three-dimensional object evolving is because you are not defining a three-dimensional object. In your modified code you have defined a set of points in the xy-plane with one associated z-value for each point. A box requires more than that.

Comment: @E.Klahn I don't understand, I did a thing very similar to yours ahah

Comment: Yes, similar but not identical. The documentation for `mlab.mesh` states that the 2D-arrays should hold the vertices of the shape you are trying to plot. And since you are only passing vertices in a plane, you are getting just that: a single plane.

Comment: @E.Klahn but you did `mlab.mesh` too!

Comment: @E.Klahn I saw your second code: it works!!! Thank you so much!! Just last question: what the command `X,Y=X.T,Y.T` does? Because without it no surface appears

Comment: Wonderful that it works! In terms of using `mlab.mesh`, you're right, I did that too. But it is a question of passing the right values. You passed it vertices that were all in a plane, and therefore you get a plane. In terms of using `X, Y = X.T, Y.T`, that code transposes the arrays X and Y. It is a requirement of the `mlab.surf` function as per the documentation (https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#surf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've shown the code to plot a cube and animate it so that it grows out from a height of 0.01 to a height of 1 using `mlab.mesh`. What `yield` does is that it returns control to the decorator so that the scene can be updated.

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

s = 0.01
X = np.array([[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1]])
Y = np.array([[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0],[1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,1]])
Z = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[s,s,s,s],[0,0,s,s],[0,0,s,s]])

m = mlab.mesh(X, Y, Z)

@mlab.animate(delay=20)
def anim():
    for i in range(1,101):
        print(i, end='\r')
        m.mlab_source.z = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[s*i,s*i,s*i,s*i],[0,0,s*i,s*i],[0,0,s*i,s*i]])
        yield

anim()
mlab.show()
```

`scalars` is one way to access the underlying data structure if that data structure has the `scalars` attribute. However, for `mesh` that attribute is not used, rather you want to access `z` and set those values. I would not know what your specific issue with `u` if unless there is a traceback to work from. The same with `yield` - I see no reason why that keyword would stop the animation at any particular step.

The code below shows, instead of a box evolving over time, a surface evolving with time.

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

def evolving_function(X, Y, t, Lx=1, Ly=1):
    
    return np.sin(X+Lx*t)*np.sin(Y+Ly*t)

Lx, Ly = 1,2

x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
y = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
X, Y = X.T, Y.T
s = evolving_function(X, Y, 0, Lx=Lx, Ly=Ly)

m = mlab.surf(X, Y, s)

dt = 50
t = 10
steps = int(10*1000/dt)

@mlab.animate(delay=dt)
def anim():
     for i in range(1,steps):
         m.mlab_source.scalars = evolving_function(X, Y, dt*i, Lx=Lx, Ly=Ly)
         yield

anim()
mlab.show()
```

Comment: I used your code (that works, but I cannot use in my case) to extend it in a case similar to mine and I get the same problem: this time something changes, the surface begins to move, but it's just a flat plane going up. I need instead, to be clear, a surface moving because I have a normalized wavefunction moving on a grid! That's why I need the surface evolving in the third dimension. In the case I considered I put just a non-normalized uniform wavefunction increasing it's height with time, similarly to your example (in which I don't understand why your matrices have that form).

Comment: I don't get too why yield should give any problems, but a friend of mine helped me debug and we found there the cause: we don't know why anyway. I edited my question to show the modifications I put to your code